# Continuous Homomorphism of Matrix Groups - counterexample

Tags: matrices, continuous-homomorphisms

Let 
{${G={\begin{bmatrix}
1 & n \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}} \in SUT_2(\mathbb R) : n\in\mathbb Z}$}. $$\\$$
For any irrational number r$\in\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$, a function is given with
$$\varphi:G\to U(1); \varphi(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & n \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}) = e^{2\pi rni}$$
I want to show, that $\varphi$ is not a continuous homomorphism of matrix groups. Therefore I want to show that $\varphi$G has limit points in U(1) which are not in $\varphi$G. Such a point is $-1+0i = e^{\pi i}$. My problem is, that im not able to find a series in $\varphi$G which has the limit point -1. $$\\$$
Any Ideas? :)

Comment: I do not know exact answer but I think that as n tending to infinity $e^{2 \pi rni}$ will make a dense subset of $S^1$ so it has limit -1 too.  If we consider the set $\{ 2 \pi rni | n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ =S then S is dense in $S^1$ clearly.

Comment: But the product of an irrational number r and a rational number n is irrational, so there is no way to get r$\cdot$n = 1/2 which is needed for e^{$\pi$ i}

Comment: I am not saying you will get r.n =1/2 for some n. I am saying that as n goes to infinity $2 \pi rni$ mod $2 \pi$ moves much faster and you will get an approximation of $\pi$. Suppose if you had a rational number r then it would have repeated the circle again and again but you have r irrational and see that for different n, it will give different value. I do not know how to prove it.