# The limit points of a sequence $a_n=\sin(2\pi{rn})$ r is a irrational number

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory

The problem is the same in this post and it is from Baker's AN INTRODUCTION TO LIE THEORY
in chapter 1.
[Continuous Homomorphism of Matrix Groups - counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2532639/1160191)

Let
\begin{equation}
G=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & n \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \in SUT_2(\mathbb{R}) : n\in\mathbb{Z} \right\}
\end{equation}

For any irrational number r$\in\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$, the function is a continuous group homomorphism.But its image is not a closed subspace of $\rm{U}(1)$ since the writer says its image is a dense proper subset of $\rm{U}(1)$,which makes me confused.
$$\varphi:G\to U(1); \varphi(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & n \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}) = e^{2\pi rni}$$

I want to show that the limits points of $\{\sin(2\pi{rn})\}$ are $[-1,1]\backslash\{\sin(2\pi{rn})\}$,so we can say the image is a dense proper subset.So I want to show that there is a subsequence:$a_{n_k}=sin(2\pi{rn_k})$ and $a_{n_k}\rightarrow{\alpha} \ \forall {\alpha}\in[-1,1]\backslash\{\sin(2\pi{rn})\}.$But how to find this kind of series?

My another idea to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$,we can find that
$$
\forall \beta \in [0,2\pi),  |2\pi{rn}-2k\pi-\beta|<\varepsilon$$ for some $n$ and some interger $k$.

Comment: so, you're looking for the closure of $\{\sin(2\pi{rn})\}$? or perhaps more directly, of $\{\exp(2\pi i{rn})\}$?

Comment: @user24142 Yes,I am looking for that.Since $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$,maybe it's easier to look the closure of {sin(2πrn)} but the closure of $exp(2\pi{rn})$

Comment: $\sin(2\pi r n)$ is a *sequence*, not at *series*. A series is an infinite **sum**.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks!I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the natural place to ask this question is on the circle, $[0,1]$ with $0$ and $1$ identified, and then removing $1$. The set of points is then $\{rn\ \mathrm{mod}\ 1\}$. Let $n' = rn\ \mathrm{mod}\ 1$ and let $A_N= \{n'\ | 0\leq n \leq N\}$.

I'm going to talk about the gaps in $A_n$. By that I mean that, as these are all numbers between $0$ and $1$, we can write them out in their natural order, and take the difference between adjacent points to get all but the last gap, which is $1$ minus the greatest element in the set. These gap calculations are essentially using $d$, the metric that exists on the circle, but also using a concept of direction perhaps (for very small sets).

I want to show that for all $M$ there is some $N$ such that the gaps between adjacent points in the set $A_N$ are all less than $1/M$.

Note that for any $k$ the sum of the gaps in $A_k$ is always $1$ and that there are $k+1$ points in $A_k$, so the smallest gap must be less than $1/k$.

So, start with $A_M$ and let its smallest gap be formed by $a'$ and $b'$ for some integers $a$ and $b$. Let $n = |a - b|$. I claim $d(a',b') = d(n', 0)$. Furthermore, for large $M$, $d((2n)', n') = d(n', 0)$ and $d((2n)', 0) = 2d(n', 0)$ ie $(2n)'$ is in the same direction from $0$ as $n'$. Some more thought will confirm for you that $$N = n\left \lfloor \frac{1}{d(n', 0)} \right\rfloor $$ has the desired properties: $A_{nM}$ will contain the points $\{(in)' | 0 \leq i \leq \lfloor 1/d(n', 0) \rfloor \}$ and these are evenly spaced around the circle, and get back to $0$, so that any point on the circle is less $1/2M$ distance from them. $M$ was arbitrary, so $\{rn\ \mathrm{mod}\ 1\}$ is dense.

There's a prettier argument for the conclusion that uses the continued fraction expansion of $r$ because the indices where the gaps in $A_n$ get better occur at values related to the numerators and denominators of the continued fraction approximations, but its tricky to get it right, and the above is enough imo.

Comment: I can get your idea of that. But I can't understand why $d((2n)', 0) = 2d(n', 0)$ and the direction you mentioned.

Comment: I get it.Does it means $d((2n)', 0) = 2d(n', 0)$ when $(2n)'$ and $n'$ are in "the same circle" since $1/M$ is suffeciently small, which is the meaning of direction.

Comment: Yeah, if you imagine  $M$ is like $10$ or something, and $n'$ is, say, clockwise from $0$, then $(2n)'$ is clockwise from $n'$ and so also clockwise from $0$. If you wanted to make the argument a bit more tedious you could define $d_r$ and $d_l$ maybe, but I'm not sure you're adding much doing that.

Comment: Thank you, I get your idea. A concise proof!

Comment: Fixed a silly error: you need enough points to get back to $0$ and I hadn't guaranteed that. Anyway, you might be able to see how continued fractions come into things via that edit.